# GUI Jpanel buttons dont work, vant postion them on screen

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

im starting to work with jpanel, but after a lot of reading and going crazy, i couldnt understand how to make it work...
so im trying to open a frame with 2 buttons, i was able  to do that, but i cant postion them in the frame, here is my code:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       


    JButton but = new JButton("text");
    but.setLocation(20, 20);
    JButton but2 = new JButton("list");
    but2.setLocation(50, 50);


    JPanel panel= new JPanel();
    panel.add(but);
    panel.add(but2);    


    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Please make a small sketch, of exactly how you want the `JButton`s to be placed on the `JPanel`, so that one can guide you in the best way. Since the `JButton`s can be placed in many different ways, using many different Layout Managers. Though avoid what you doing right now, i.e. the use of `Absolute Positioning`, which is highly discouraged approach in Java Swing :-)

Comment: The answer lies in giving up trying to place components manually at certain pixel positions. Swing is designed to be used with layout managers, and going against that results in no end of trouble.

To select which layout manager is the most appropriate for your purposes, take a look at the [visual guide to layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: [link] (http://www.mediafire.com/?bvp73512g9oh108) here is a photo of what i am trying to do